# AWK/BASH: how to match a field in one file from a field in another?

Tags: bash, shell, file, awk

I have 2 files, the first contains the following:

```
...
John Allen Smith II 16 555-555-5555 10/24/2010
John Allen Smith II 3 555-555-5555 10/24/2010
John Allen Smith II 17 555-555-5555 10/24/2010
John Doe 16 555-555-5555 10/24/2010
Jane Smith 16 555-555-5555 9/16/2010
Jane Smith 00 555-555-5555 10/24/2010
...
```

and the second file is a list of names so...

```
...
John Allen Smith II
John Doe
Jane Smith
...
```

Is it possible to use awk (or other bash command) to print the lines in the first file that match any name in the second file (the names can repeat in the first file)

Bonus? Is there an easy way to remove those repeated/duplicate lines in the first file?

Thanks very much,

Tomek

Comment: If there are 2 lines that are equal, one is left behind. Is that your definition of "remove" duplicated lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk

```
#! /bin/bash
awk 'FNR==NR{!a[$0]++;next }{ b[$0]++ }
END{
  for(i in a){
    for(k in b){
      if (a[i]==1 && i ~ k ) { print i }
    }
  }
}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` as:

```
grep -f file2 file1   # file2 is the file with the names.
```

The `-f` option of `grep` obtains the pattern to be search for from the file.

To remove exact duplicate lines from the output you can use `sort` as:

```
grep -f file2 file1 | sort -u
```

Comment: I tried to use the command but got the following, "grep: Unmatched [ or [^", I then tried using -F to force but there was no output? Is this command using all of file2 in one search pattern to try and match to file1?

Comment: I specified the -F flag wrong (I replaced -f with -F) so the final command grep -f file2 -F file1 worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: for the unique, I was looking to remove the lines from file1 that have just the names repeated (the other columns have different data)

Comment: If there is a chance of duplicate lines being everywhere, sort is needed.

Comment: @ghostdog74 duplicate lines(names) only occur in the same place right after each other, the problem is that the rest of the line (after the name) can be different.

Answer (score 1):

expanding on codaddict's answer:

```
grep -f file2 file1 | sort | uniq
```

this will remove lines that are exactly the same, but the side effect (which may be unwanted) is that your datafile will now be sorted.
It also requires the lines to be **exactly** the same, which is not the case in your example data.  The names are the same, but the data after those same names is different. `uniq` can take a field or character count option, but this won't work on your data because your names have variable length and a variable number of fields. If you know your data fields are always the last 3 fields on a line, then you can do this:

```
grep -f file2 file1 | sort | rev | uniq -f 3 | rev
```

your output will be only one of each name, but which one? the lowest one lexicographically because it was sorted (`sort` is needed for `uniq` to work right). If you don't want to sort it first, or need to be careful about which of the lines are dropped, then an awk or perl or ruby or python solution will probably work best using associative arrays.

Comment: Yea that's exactly my problem. The names can be of variable length and the data after the name is different. I am just looking to get the first occurrence of say John Allen Smith II. I'll look into some associative arrays with awk. Thanks for the info.